# return from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, return

In Ruby an explicit return inside a method is normally placed before an expression and returns the value of that expression, like in the code below:

```
def method_with_explicit_return
  :a_non_return_value
  return :return_value
  :another_non_return_value
end

assert_equal :return_value, method_with_explicit_return
```

Unless a conditional is used and evaluated (like in `return :return_value unless a < b`), any piece of code that comes after the return expression is ignored.

In Ruby on Rails I came across the following expression inside a controller action:

```
redirect_to root_url and return
```

Why `return` is placed at the end of the `redirect_to` expression and what is its function?

Comment: `and return` makes sure that execution is halted after redirect.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, `redirect_to` will not return from the method but only sets up headers for the response. You have to explicitly return for it to stop execution and proceed with the response. You can also write that code like,

```
return redirect_to root_url
```